# How to implement bootstrap-datepicker as Aurelia custom element

Tags: aurelia

Having first read this http://www.danyow.net/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-aurelia/ and with inspiration from  https://gist.github.com/charlespockert/6a1fef3f546f6d37d1dc here follows my attempt to implement the https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker version of bootstrap datepicker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/TkbT6E?p=preview

I'm getting `self.datePicker.datepicker is not a function(…)` although I've checked that bootstrap-datepicker is correctly installed with jspm and that the .js is loaded. The datepicker does show up (which confirms that the js is loaded correctly), and I can select a date, but the value is not set.

What am I doing wrong here?

Update:

A friendly soul ,@SamDeBlock, in gitter.im/Aurelia put together this http://plnkr.co/edit/hKit8pigwL1ijr2DmbGP?p=preview with the dependencies so it'll run. I keep getting the above error however, when running this in my own application. I'm gonna investigate it problem further and update here, if I get to the bottom of this.

**Update 2:**

I've now located the problem down to being an issue with system.js/jspm. That's also why the above plunkr works, since it just reference the files directly instead of defining them in config.js.

**If I add the file manually** like proposed in the above plunkr - AND if I change the following in moment.js file from:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    global.moment = factory()
}(this, function () { 'use strict';
...
```

to:

```
(function (global = typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    global.moment = factory()
}(this, function () { 'use strict';
...
```

the `global = typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this` part..

THEN it seems to work, with the Aurelia navigation skeleton as well.

But why is this necessary? And how can I get this to work, without all the hacks? I've built my application on the Aurelia Navigation Starter project
https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation

Comment: The plunker does not load correctly, there are 404 errors for `moments.js` and `bootstrap-datepicker.js`.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/hKit8pigwL1ijr2DmbGP?p=preview - but my problem is that it does seem to work in that plunkr, but it keeps writing datepicker is not a function in my application.

Comment: You might consider changing the subject of your question to something related to module loading issues instead of something about how to implement a datepicker. I think the question would then attract more people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are that jspm caused this when doing `jspm install -y npm:bootstrap-datepicker`so check in config.js

Look for this:

```
"npm:bootstrap-datepicker@1.5.0": {
  "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
  "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.1.4"
},
```

And change it to this:

```
"npm:bootstrap-datepicker@1.5.0": {
  "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
  "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.4"
},
```

The important part being: `"jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.4"`

Then everything should work through System.config without the need for the moment.js workaround or anything else.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OeVeiLXwfpTlorDZjBQe?p=preview

Comment: worth noting that if you have `github:twbs/bootstrap` defined 
you need to comment out the dependency on `jquery`